# Turning on an automotive relay when enough voltage is available

Tags: relay, automotive, zener, voltage-clipping

I'm trying to drive a relay off a dome light in a car, where the dome light fades in smoothly. That is, say, I have a constant ground and the other wire goes from 0 to 12V (up to 14V) over a couple seconds. The dimmer is being run by the car's computer.

While the relay does come on, it does so while making a sound of entering a hyperspace. I figured the sound is due to the relay not getting enough voltage during the initial startup. In so far, I've tried a zener diode in series. 5v zener reduces the noise, but not completely. 10v zener is not enough to activate the relay (datasheet claims coil activation is around 8v) due to zener voltage drop. I also tried a capacitor in parallel to the coil 560mu 36V I had laying around seems to work the best. 300mu 24V and smaller did not seem to work. Still, being an automotive application, I'd rather not have a large electrolytic capacitor near the hot roof. Is there a better yet simple solution? A comparator using zener as a reference seems like an overkill. I can also try a much smaller PCB-type relay with a hope of it being more tolerant to the startup conditions. Any suggestions? Bonus points for not frying the car's computer that drives the dimmer!

EDIT:  I have simplified a bit. In reality, I have 3 wires: 12+, ground, and 'door'. With the door closed, the 'door' wire is at 12+, when the door opens - the 'door' wire goes to close to 0. My goal is to convert the 'door' wire into 'interrupted 12+' (no signal when door closed, positive when door open) required by a dimmable mirror.

EDIT2: Would simply comparing ground to 'door' signal make more sense?

EDIT3: My ultimate goals are 1) to provide a positive 'door' signal to a Gentex 221 mirror that came from a Ford using a 'door' signal from Toyota that, upon opening the door, goes from +12V to 0V; 2) trigger a Hella timer relay that feeds +12V to this mirror. My original plan was to use the Toyota door signal to trigger a second relay that would send +12V to the mirror's door pin.

Upon much struggle with the chatter on the relay, I realized I don't actually need the second relay. All it takes is a PNP transistor like 2N3906. The base goes to the Toyota door signal, Emitter goes to +12V, and Collector goes to Gentex door pin. This setup essentially reverses the +12->0 signal from Toyota into a 0->+12 signal sufficient to drive the Timer relay and the mirror's door function.

Now, I'm not 100% positive why the timer relay does not exhibit a chatter; most likely because I'm switching on the full +12V rather than the PWM'd ground.

Comment: Is one side of the bulb grounded or is one side connected to +12?

Comment: Your trying to capture an pwm or otherwise modulated signal. Use a microcontroller and level translation to trigger off it and control the relay.

Comment: entering hyperspace makes a sound? ... in vacuum? ... how?

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany I have updated the description, hope it clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Turns out everything was way simpler than I thought. Live and learn!

Comment: @maksym you can and should move your solution to an answer. It's okay to answer your own question.

Comment: @Passerby Fair enough. Added as an answer. I'm still keeping the edit in the question since it explains the though process.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach (this assumes the bulb has one side grounded, if not then just flip everything over and use a P-channel MOSFET).

The idea is that the PWM signal to the bulb discharges the capacitor C1 (through Lamp1 and D1) during the 'off' part of the PWM cycle until the lamp is almost completely on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUVu6R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The OP requires the dimmer output to switch on the relay. I presume there is no 12V line nearby.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I do have 3 wires - 12V, ground, and PWM. My goal is to convert PWM back to discrete 12V/no 12V.

Comment: Does the bulb play an active role in the circuit? Can we take it out or replace with a smaller resistance and still get the same behavior?

Comment: Yes, the bulb discharges C1 when the high-side switch turns off. The resistance is not critical, provided it's a resistor or tungsten bulb and not an LED.

Comment: If you don't have the 12V nearby you can connect that node directly to the lamp (assuming high-side switch) and it still should work.

Comment: The bulb is indeed an LED and I'd like to keep it out of the circuit anyway (that is, everything should still work with bulb out). I guess I'll give it a try with a resistor in place of the bulb!

Comment: A short update. More parts under way. Will update once I can assemble the circuit to the specs!

Comment: I made this work with the following changes. Since there is no lamp1, I have connected Lamp1 wire to the collector of the mosfet. I also changed the capacitor to 10uf, which is still electorolytic, but a lot smaller one. 1uf was still turning on too soon. It seems 10uf turns on a little after the PWM wire (ground in my case) reaches the full 12V potential. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I take it back. 10uf are available in ceramic and tantalum as well, although temperature ratings are not necessary much better.

Comment: 4.7uf worked too!

Answer (score 1):

I realized I don't actually need the second relay. All it takes is a PNP transistor like 2N3906. The base goes to the Toyota door signal, Emitter goes to +12V, and Collector goes to Gentex door pin. This setup essentially reverses the +12->0 signal from Toyota into a 0->+12 signal sufficient to drive the Timer relay and the mirror's door function.

Now, I'm not 100% positive why the timer relay does not exhibit a chatter. One possible reason is because I'm switching on the full +12V rather than the PWM'd ground. Second reason is the timer relay measures 100 kOhms while the normal relay is 10 ohms, perhaps because of a built-in resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one using a transistor to drive the relay.

[image]

The schematic has been altered to show the relay being fed by +12V instead of the dimmer output.

[image]

Comment: Would I get any benefits from using a comparator as opposed to the transistor? Also, can I substitute with a different zener (say 10V) without changing other components of the circuit?

Comment: Maksym, It's a 10V Zener only. The error has been corrected thanks to you!  I suppose the transistor circuit is good enough for the requirement.

Comment: Thanks! 8V zener should work as well, but 10V is closer to where I'de like to turn it on. Since, in addition to the signal door wire, I have a ground and a 12V (see the updated description) - would it make more sense to throw away zener and just use the ground as a reference?

Comment: Hi Maksym, After going through your edits, it appears that your original scheme is the right one. Your objective is to simulate the door switch using a relay which is energised by the voltage across the dome light. Using the relay contacts, the voltage applied to the dimmable mirror is to be 0V with the door closed and +12V with the door open. This scheme effectively avoids any interfacing with the 'Door Switch' input of the ECU. My schematic is to be altered to show how the supply to the dimmable mirror is switched.

Comment: Nah, your schematics is correct. My only 'door' signal is the dimmer wire; I'm trying to convert this dimmer signal into a more binary door switch signal. I will try to assemble your schema and accept the answer if I see if it works good enough. I don't see why it wouldn't though; l though of this approach myself, but was curious if I can get away without using transistors and other logic elements.

Comment: Hi Maksym, Relay contact wiring is added.

Comment: I tried to put this together with a transistor I had laying around and a led bulb in place of relay. As you raise the voltage from 0 to 11V, what appears to happen is the back voltage across zener would start to raise slowly once you go above 10V. At some point, the transistor would slowly turn in and starts conducting, but not completely. The whole thing stabilizes around 10.5V, so between 10V and 10.5V you still get a dimmer effect as the input voltage climbs from 10V to 10.5V. I might need another transistor driven by the first transistor, or amplify the signal from zener.

Comment: Hi Maksym, I checked it out using a 8.2V Zener (couldn't find a 10V one!) and a 12V DC 185Ω relay while increasing the supply voltage from 0-12V. After Zener breakdown starts the relay contact moves slowly and changes over with a click as the voltage increases. At 12V the voltage drop across the transistor is less than 0.2V. You would need to check with a higher gain transistor and a relay, using the dimmer supply.

Comment: A short update. More parts under way. Will update once I can assemble the circuit to the specs!

Comment: I've tried 2N3904 with no luck.Although a different relay might do better,I feel PWM and the time it takes computer to fade-in (at least 2 seconds) is a bigger issue that requires some kind of capacitor to smooth out the signal and introduce a time delay. Otherwise, we just compressing the wave, but not changing its basic shape. The other suggested solution down below worked with a 10um capacitor, but did not quite work with 1um. I think my next step would be to get a bench power supply so I don't have to plug this into the car and maybe throw in another transistor for a cascade amplification.

Comment: Hi Maksym, I have altered the schematic to show the relay being fed by +12V instead of the dimmer output. You may try this to see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you, @vu2nan. How would you change the circuit if the dimming wire is the Ground? That is, it is normally positive, and when the door opens - it fades to ground?In other words, I have the following wires: +12, ground, and the dimmer wire.The relay should close when the dimmer wire is equal or close to ground potential. Since the is no  opposite of zener, I think I can use +12V and the dimmer wire as ground for your circuit. Then, the collector of this circuit would drive a PNP transistor.The PNP transistor will be connected to a true ground and will drive the relay. Does this make sense?

Comment: Hi Maksym, In your present configuration, one terminal of the dome light bulb is connected to the dimmer output with the other terminal floating when the doors are closed. When any door is opened the floating terminal is connected to ground through a door switch. I do not understand how the dimmer output could be treated as ground.

Comment: vu2nan. It is Toyota and they like doing things different. The dome light has three wires: ground, constant +12V and a 'door fade' wire. The door fade wire is controlled by a computer. When the door closed, this wire is +12V, when the door opens - it fades to close to 0V. Now, the dome light itself has two modes. The 'always-on' mode connects an LED to +12V and ground. The 'door' mode connects +12V to 'door fade' wire; in this mode, when the door closed, both wires sit at +12, so there is no current flowing. When the door is open, the door wire becomes 0V and LED lights up.

Comment: This setup is different from most other cars, thus my attempt to convert the door wire to be able to retrofit a Ford mirror. Sorry for the initial confusion. I realize I spent too much of your time already - feel free to abandon this 'project'. I did learn a ton in the last couple weeks though, particularly about different types of transistors and is now more comfortable using them as opposed to relays. I also think my chatter problem comes with the fact that most automotive relays come with a built-in resistor, so they take a lot more juice to turn on.

Comment: Hi Maksym, I got it, but only after going through your Edit3, your comments and your answer just now! I understand that you have solved your problem by using the door switch to turn on a 2N3906 to directly switch +12V to the 100KΩ input of the Hella Timer. Thank you very much for providing an opportunity for some brain-racking.

Comment: Thank you  vu2nan! I actually did modify your circuit to drive 2N3906 to drive the relay. That did not work quite exactly as I wanted, but was pretty close. While troubleshooting the circuit, I realized I do not need the binary behavior of the relay as the fade-in output of 2N3906 was likely to be ok with the mirror. In other words, your answer is what ultimately lead me to the solution.Wish I could accept your answer to give you a credit,but it is not solving my problem yet. I plan on getting a PSU and oscilloscope to troubleshoot this further. I feel there is a lot more for me to learn!

Comment: You are most welcome, Maksym. Not to worry about credits for the answer. Have fun!